# MongoDB server freeze - large amount of collections

Tags: mongodb, freeze, rocksdb, large-data

We have large MongoDB database (about 1,4mln collections), MongoDB 3.0, engine rocksDB, operating system Ubuntu 14.04.

This DB is located on virtual machine (VmWare vCloud) with 16 cores and 108 GB RAM (currently mongoDB used 70GB of memory without swap).

Production setup options:

- data on dedicated partition - XFS filesystem
- transparent_hugepage enabled - never
- transparent_hugepage defrag - never

DB stats:

```
{
    "db" : "ctp",
    "collections" : 1369486,
    "objects" : 20566852,
    "avgObjSize" : 1126.82749999854,
    "dataSize" : 23175294422,
    "storageSize" : 23231888384,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "indexes" : 6686175,
    "indexSize" : 685981393,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Sample collections sizes:

```
{
    "ns" : "ctp._cf123_ct49_dfc-r_dtc-r_tof2_groupat",
    "count" : 33,
    "size" : 38172,
    "avgObjSize" : 1156,
    "storageSize" : 38144,
    "capped" : false,
    "nindexes" : 5,
    "totalIndexSize" : 6312,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 18,
        "exAt" : 16,
        "unique" : 6246,
        "_smp" : 10,
        "_smpdf" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1
}

{
    "ns" : "ctp._afpoznan123_atlondyn49_df2016-09_dt2016-09_tof2_groupdfdt",
    "count" : 188,
    "size" : 208677,
    "avgObjSize" : 1109,
    "storageSize" : 208640,
    "capped" : false,
    "nindexes" : 5,
    "totalIndexSize" : 7945,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 2845,
        "exAt" : 256,
        "_smp" : 160,
        "_smpdf" : 352,
        "unique" : 4332
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
{
    "ns" : "ctp._cf123_ct42_dfc-r_dtc-r_tof2_groupat",
    "count" : 27,
    "size" : 30400,
    "avgObjSize" : 1125,
    "storageSize" : 30208,
    "capped" : false,
    "nindexes" : 5,
    "totalIndexSize" : 84,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 18,
        "exAt" : 16,
        "unique" : 18,
        "_smp" : 10,
        "_smpdf" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Periodically every 5 minutes is running script which writes to these collections and creates new one if this collection doesn't exists (collections names are based on data which are inside these collections) and creating indexes.

We've noticed that this server has some freezes during writing data to collections. This kind of freeze can take from 5 to 60 seconds.

Has anyone experienced this issue and could help us?

Here are some logs from moment of freeze:

```
db.currentOP();

  "opid" : 22717868,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._cf115_atboma25_dfc-r_dtc-r_tof2_groupdfym",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {
                "T#df" : {
                    "$lt" : "2017-02-28"
                }
            },
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:33832",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(22004831)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135907",
        "threadId" : "0xc3e5d64e0",
        "connectionId" : 135907,
        "opid" : 22719375,
        "active" : true,
        "secs_running" : 0,
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(223601),
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "top_search.top_searches",
        "query" : {
            "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
        },
        "planSummary" : "IXSCAN { T#df: 1, T#dt: 1 }",
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:33648",
        "numYields" : 170,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r",
            "Collection" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(342)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(171)
                }
            },
            "Collection" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(171)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135959",
        "threadId" : "0x10d4445260",
        "connectionId" : 135959,
        "opid" : 22718533,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._afoxford-house23_attamarindo32_dfc-r_dtc-r_tof2_groupdfdt",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {},
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1),
                "T#df" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:34022",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(15003580)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135829",
        "threadId" : "0x10d4445740",
        "connectionId" : 135829,
        "opid" : 22717923,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._ct123_dfc-r_dtc-r_tof2_groupdfym",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {
                "T#df" : {
                    "$lt" : "2017-02-28"
                }
            },
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:33026",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(21004810)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135781",
        "threadId" : "0x2d678e0",
        "connectionId" : 135781,
        "opid" : 22718920,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._cf1147_atrostock36_df2016-06_dtc-r_tof2_groupaf",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {},
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:60874",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(12002770)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135870",
        "threadId" : "0xd04ed5d40",
        "connectionId" : 135870,
        "opid" : 22719172,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._cf61_atpristina131_dfc-r_dtc-r_tof2_groupaf",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {},
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:33369",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(7001590)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135687",
        "threadId" : "0xc3e5d7380",
        "connectionId" : 135687,
        "opid" : 22717925,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._cf105_athana156_df2016-06_dt2016-06_tof2_groupaf",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {},
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:60022",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(21003871)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135754",
        "threadId" : "0xd04ed5860",
        "connectionId" : 135754,
        "opid" : 22718485,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._cf5_atdhaka1113_dfc-r_dtc-r_tof2_groupaf",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {},
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:60603",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(15503084)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135644",
        "threadId" : "0xc3e5d9c20",
        "connectionId" : 135644,
        "opid" : 22719073,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._afgenua71_ataarhus37_dfc-r_dtc-r_tof2_groupdfdt",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {},
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1),
                "T#df" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:59698",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(7501602)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135891",
        "threadId" : "0xd04ed7a80",
        "connectionId" : 135891,
        "opid" : 22719284,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._attianjin30_dfc-r_dtc-r_tof2_groupcf",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {},
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:33530",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(3000658)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135673",
        "threadId" : "0xd04ed6220",
        "connectionId" : 135673,
        "opid" : 22718185,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._afwroclaw123_atlondyn49_df2016-06_dt2016-06_tof2_groupdfdt",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {},
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1),
                "T#df" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:59925",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(16503737)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135989",
        "threadId" : "0x10d44443c0",
        "connectionId" : 135989,
        "opid" : 22719240,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._cf28_atmarakesz93_dfc-r_dtc-r_tof2_groupaf",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {},
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:34367",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(4500947)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135410",
        "threadId" : "0x2d66220",
        "connectionId" : 135410,
        "opid" : 22717853,
        "active" : true,
        "secs_running" : 22,
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(22406019),
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp.$cmd",
        "query" : {
            "createIndexes" : "_cf71_df2016-07_dt2016-11_tof2_groupct",
            "indexes" : [ 
                {
                    "key" : {
                        "expireAt" : 1
                    },
                    "name" : "exAt",
                    "background" : true,
                    "expireAfterSeconds" : 0
                }
            ]
        },
        "client" : "0.0.0.0:0",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "w",
            "Database" : "W"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(376227),
                    "w" : NumberLong(15477)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(180375),
                    "w" : NumberLong(15476),
                    "W" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "W" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "W" : NumberLong(22004935)
                }
            },
            "Collection" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(180375),
                    "w" : NumberLong(15476)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135961",
        "threadId" : "0x10d4442b60",
        "connectionId" : 135961,
        "opid" : 22718537,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._cf5_atattawapiskat23_dfc-r_dtc-r_tof2_groupaf",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {},
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:34029",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(15002978)
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        "desc" : "conn135905",
        "threadId" : "0xc3e5d6000",
        "connectionId" : 135905,
        "opid" : 22718186,
        "active" : false,
        "op" : "query",
        "ns" : "ctp._afwarszawa123_atdubrownik61_df2016-08_dt2016-08_tof2_groupdfdt",
        "query" : {
            "$query" : {},
            "$orderby" : {
                "T#mp" : NumberLong(1),
                "T#df" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "client" : "192.168.1.33:33638",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "r",
            "Database" : "r"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(16503305)
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

---

```
db.serverStatus()["rocksdb"];

{
    "stats" : [ 
        "", 
        "** Compaction Stats [default] **", 
        "Level    Files   Size(MB) Score Read(GB)  Rn(GB) Rnp1(GB) Write(GB) Wnew(GB) Moved(GB) W-Amp Rd(MB/s) Wr(MB/s) Comp(sec) Comp(cnt) Avg(sec) Stall(cnt)  KeyIn KeyDrop", 
        "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", 
        "  L0      0/0       0.00   0.0      0.0     0.0      0.0       1.4      1.4       0.0   0.0      0.0    120.1        12        39    0.312          0       0      0", 
        "  L4      0/0       0.00   0.0      1.8     1.8      0.0       1.7      1.7       0.0   1.0    102.0     99.7        18        11    1.606          7     21M   153K", 
        "  L5     15/0     620.47   1.0      6.6     1.4      5.2       5.5      0.3       0.0   3.9     44.4     37.0       152        25    6.086          0    110M   840K", 
        "  L6    106/0    6401.43   0.0      3.5     0.3      3.3       3.3     -0.0       0.0  12.6     25.9     23.7       140         7   20.057          0    162M    14M", 
        " Sum    121/0    7021.90   0.0     11.9     3.4      8.5      11.9      3.4       0.0   8.3     37.8     37.8       322        82    3.932          7    295M    15M", 
        " Int      0/0       0.00   0.0      0.0     0.0      0.0       0.0      0.0       0.0   0.0      0.0      0.0         0         0    0.000          0       0      0", 
        "Flush(GB): cumulative 1.429, interval 0.000", 
        "Stalls(count): 0 level0_slowdown, 0 level0_slowdown_with_compaction, 0 level0_numfiles, 0 level0_numfiles_with_compaction, 0 pending_compaction_bytes, 0 memtable_compaction, 7 leveln_slowdown_soft, 0 leveln_slowdown_hard", 
        "", 
        "** DB Stats **", 
        "Uptime(secs): 34952.0 total, 0.2 interval", 
        "Cumulative writes: 4990K writes, 17M keys, 4989K batches, 1.0 writes per batch, ingest: 2.02 GB, 0.06 MB/s", 
        "Cumulative WAL: 4990K writes, 0 syncs, 4990122.00 writes per sync, written: 2.02 GB, 0.06 MB/s", 
        "Cumulative compaction: 11.90 GB write, 0.35 MB/s write, 11.90 GB read, 0.35 MB/s read, 322.4 seconds", 
        "Cumulative stall: 00:00:3.548 H:M:S, 0.0 percent", 
        "Interval writes: 0 writes, 0 keys, 0 batches, 0.0 writes per batch, ingest: 0.00 MB, 0.00 MB/s", 
        "Interval WAL: 0 writes, 0 syncs, 0.00 writes per sync, written: 0.00 MB, 0.00 MB/s", 
        "Interval compaction: 0.00 GB write, 0.00 MB/s write, 0.00 GB read, 0.00 MB/s read, 0.0 seconds", 
        "Interval stall: 00:00:0.000 H:M:S, 0.0 percent"
    ],
    "num-immutable-mem-table" : "0",
    "mem-table-flush-pending" : "0",
    "compaction-pending" : "0",
    "background-errors" : "0",
    "cur-size-active-mem-table" : "33MB",
    "cur-size-all-mem-tables" : "33MB",
    "num-entries-active-mem-table" : "185495",
    "num-entries-imm-mem-tables" : "0",
    "estimate-table-readers-mem" : "91MB",
    "num-snapshots" : "1",
    "oldest-snapshot-time" : "1465911051",
    "num-live-versions" : "1",
    "total-live-recovery-units" : 60,
    "block-cache-usage" : "34GB",
    "transaction-engine-keys" : NumberLong(4210),
    "transaction-engine-snapshots" : NumberLong(1),
    "thread-status" : []
}
```

---

```
db.serverStatus()['globalLock'];

{
    "totalTime" : NumberLong(34952090000),
    "currentQueue" : {
        "total" : 57,
        "readers" : 56,
        "writers" : 1
    },
    "activeClients" : {
        "total" : 124,
        "readers" : 57,
        "writers" : 1
    }
}
```

---

And screen from mongostat:
[image: screen from mongostat]

Best Regards

Comment: what is the size of created collections? are they indexed in same moment?

Comment: I've updated this informations in my post

Answer (score 1):

Creation of new collections has no point. It is an engineering flaw. 
This amount of collections surely will freeze db server because it is forced to walk over list of available collections and check a presence of collection in the list. Also, I believe, the are some operations like metadata updates involved.

From the operations log it is getting clear that building an index takes significant time

```
"query" : {
        "createIndexes" : "_cf71_df2016-07_dt2016-11_tof2_groupct",
        "indexes" : [ 
            {
                "key" : {
                    "expireAt" : 1
                },
                "name" : "exAt",
                "background" : true,
                "expireAfterSeconds" : 0
            }
        ]
    }
```

Also, things like acquiring locks take time, which are necessary for creation new namespace and index building. 
Again, parameters like `"expireAfterSeconds" : 0` are not wise in such scale. Basically, you will have to run 1.4M timers every 60 seconds to find and prune expired records and ensure that index will be rebuilt (see those deletes on mongostat).

Please, consider changes toward reducing number of collections or splitting collections between deployments. Also you can drop indexes for inactive collections. Also, it would be wise to drop all empty & unused collections.

For immediate solution you have to find current bottlenecks: RAM, CPU or IOpS.
You have extra RAM, you can give it to MongoDB, it will help to cache more and avoid unnecessary reads. Measure your IOpS via `iostat` to see how busy is your drive.